# How to get the email of the current user in Silverlight 4 Business Application?

Tags: wcf, security, silverlight-4.0, forms-authentication, wcf-security

I am using a custom `MembershipProvider` (using EF, rather than Sql) with a SL4 business application.

The default implementation of the `MembershipUser` class has an e-mail address property, however the `User` object defined by the SL4 Business Application template (inheriting from `UserBase` )does not give you access to the Email property.

Moreover when the `AuthenticationService` (inheriting from `AuthenticationBase<User>`) does not even attempt to read the user's e-mail.

Is there a way to access the Email property of the MembershipUser(server side)/User(client side) by using the AuthenticationService, or do I have to create my own routines to return the right properties of the user?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own User class as long as you implement IUser.

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    #region Implementation of IUser
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

You can modify the `AuthenticationService` to Implement `IAuthentication<User>` and implement Login.  As part of your implemented `Login` process you can populate the `User.Email`.

```
public class AuthenticationService : DomainService, IAuthentication<User>
{
      public User Login(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, string customData)
      { 
           //can populate User.Email on successful login.
      }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that the `AuthenticationBase<User>` already implements `Login()` method, but it's not declared as virtual because it's declared in `IAuthentication<User>` interface. Can I hide it using the new operator? as in `public new User Login(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, string customData)` ?

Comment: Well, I just tried this and it didn't work. You can't hide methods of a base DomainService class. So the answer here is slightly different. Add the email as a profile property in the Web.config, add it to the User object as an automatic property, and finally override the `protected override void UpdateUserCore(User user)` method of the `AuthenticationBase<User>` so that it will update the Email in the membership user.

Comment: So, you don't want to have to implement Login?  Is that the problem?  I use the solution I posted to populate User with IpAddress so it's available at the client.